# Increase heap size by ant script

Tags: ant

We are facing langOutOfMemory error, when we run an ant script, basically this script runs a lot tests. One solution is to increase heap size using ANT_OPTS variable in environment. But the problem here is I want to increase heap size via ant script itself.

I have tried couple of ways, but neither helped:

```
<target name="test1">
     <exec executable="ant" dir="${TEST}">
           <env key="ANT_OPTS" value="-Xmx2048m"/>
      </exec>
</target>


<target name="test1" dir="{TEST}">
      <exec executable="sh">
         <arg line="ant"/>
         <env key="ANT_OPTS" value="-Xmx2048m"/>
      </exec>
</target>
```

Please help on this.

Thanks,

Ashok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run ant within ant using the exec.  This is pretty convoluted.  As document exec is meant to run system commands.

> We are facing langOutOfMemory error, when we run an ant script,
>   basically this script runs a lot tests

Assuming you are running unit tests written in junit using [ant junit task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html), you can use the `maxmemory` parameter to specify the memory to be used.  You should also be setting `fork` to true.

If this is not the case, please edit the question with the relevant portion of the ant script.

Comment: Raghu, thanks for your prompt reply. Actually in our ant script it will do lot of operations like setting paths,copying, installing some softwares etc.., for junit, fork is already enabled.